# How do I edit StyleCop settings in MonoDevelop-Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop, stylecop

How do I edit StyleCop settings in MonoDevelop-Unity?

I read about StyleCop.Settings file and a visual editor but I can't find any detailed info about how to create and edit that file.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MonoDevelop right click on the assembly "Assembly_CSharp", the select "StyleCop Settings".
[image: right click Assembly_CSharp and select StyleCop Settings]

Give the UI several seconds to come up and then you can search for a style cop rule and deselect it. This will create or modify a XML file called "Settings.StyleCop" in the Assets folder of your Unity project.
[image: StyleCop UI with rules]